# Apache no matching directory

Tags: apache, codeigniter

Why am I having this no matching directory, but I have one that was working the other day, but now it isn't. I'm using Codeigniter.

> [Sun Feb 19 11:43:03.077759 2017] [autoindex:error] [pid 5204:tid 1864] [client ::1:51750] AH01276: Cannot serve directory C:/xampp/htdocs/Groupie/assets/files/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.pl,index.cgi,index.asp,index.shtml,index.html,index.htm,default.php,default.pl,default.cgi,default.asp,default.shtml,default.html,default.htm,home.php,home.pl,home.cgi,home.asp,home.shtml,home.html,home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: http://localhost/Groupie/newsfeed

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in `C:/xampp/htdocs/Groupie/assets/files/` you don't have a file that can be served as a directory index when that directory is visited. Add one of the files in the list:

> index.php,index.pl,index.cgi,index.asp,index.shtml,index.html,index.htm,default.php,default.pl,default.cgi,default.asp,default.shtml,default.html,default.htm,home.php,home.pl,home.cgi,home.asp,home.shtml,home.html,home.htm

Comment: should i add it inside the folder?

Comment: now my whole base_url() is either not found or forbidden what seems to be wrong

Comment: Yes you can add it in the folder to resolve the error you asked about.